# how to make an amplifier system to boost my wifi over large distance?

Tags: amplifier, wifi

I am keen to know if I can build a amplifier system which would take my wifi signal as input and boost it over large distance. I know wifi repeaters are out there but I am looking for more powerful means.
This is just for information purpose. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Wifi is two-way communications such as from the router to a local android phone - both directions would need amplification at their respective transmission sources. Have you considered how nearly-impossible this will be to implement on an android phone.

Comment: Pringles cans...?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because specific design questions are required.

Comment: If its possible two implement two way connections of such amplified sources, then will it be possible to think such a point?
If we can make two bidirectional amplification, can we have this possible?

Comment: Replace your antenna with a "High Gain" antenna.

Comment: Fairly assuming my source is 2.5GHz, what kind of gain amplification am I looking here?
Will it broadcast my SSID as a repeater would?

Answer (score 4):

No, *you* can't.  Power amplifiers at a few GHz frequency are not trivial to design, and in this case it needs to be bi-directional.  Therefore, for anyone that comes here asking the question so simplistically, the answer is "No".

It is technically possible, but would be something a experienced professional would have think about carefully.  Then there is the issue of regulatory compliance.  Such a device would be illegal in most jurisdictions.

Something much more simple that you can possibly do yourself is to use a directional antenna.  Something metal that reflects at a few GHz and parabolically shaped will concentrate the received RF power along one specific direction at its focus.  This only works if you know the direction to the other device and can point the antenna in that direction.

Such a directional antenna would still be illegal in most jurisdictions.  Generally it is the maximum power you transmit in any direction that is the legally limiting factor.

Comment: thank you! 
Since it was just for an informational inclination, glad I could know its limitations.